# How do i clear a description argument?

Tags: r

Good afternoon, I received an R script from my professor to act on files on my computer. More specifically it is supposed to go into the file and read the data and perform two very specific calculations and add two values to the spreadsheet to my understanding. It seems like the pathing issue is clear but i have a new error when i attempt to run the code

source("C:/Users/JNunl/OneDrive/Desktop/DASCRIPT.R")
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

I have launched R studio
Created a new project with the working directory being the same folder the programs are in
Made sure i had downloaded the right libraries needed to run the script
Double checked the path was correct
Launched the script
Imported the dataset(idk if that nessesary but have done it anyway)
Run the line of code in question and it returns this error

I have tried to remove the last section with the file name and it does run that but i get errors for the rest of the program

Below is the code in question:

```
library(seacarb)

library(readxl)

library(lubridate)



setwd("~/")



myf=list.files(pattern="csv")

para=c("YEAR", "MONTH", "STATION_ID",            "STN_DEPTH_M",            "LATITUDE",                "LONGITUDE","SAMPLING_DATE","SAMPLE_DEPTH_M","DEPTH_CODE",               "MEDIUM",                "SAMPLE_ID",   "VALUE_1",        "VALUE_2", "VALUE_3")



result=NULL

for(i in 1: length(myf)){
  
  out=read.csv(myf[i], header=T)[para]
  
  result=rbind(result, out)
  
}



colnames(result)=c("Yr","Mn", "Stn","Std","Lat","Lon","Sdt","Spd","Dc", "Med", "SID",    "Alk",    "pH", "T")



a=subset(result, Med =="surface water")



a$Alk=as.numeric(a$Alk)

a$pH=as.numeric(a$pH)

a$T=as.numeric(a$T)

a$Mn=month(as.Date(a$Sdt))



a=subset(a, Alk>50 & Alk<125)



a=subset(a, !is.na(Alk) & !is.na(pH) & !is.na(T))



b=carb(flag=8, var1=a$pH, var2=a$Alk/50000, T=a$T, S=0.2, P=1, Pt=0.3e-9, Sit =10e-6, k1k2="r", pHscale ="F")

a$DIC=b$DIC*12000

a$pCO2=b$pCO2



stns=read_excel("stn.xlsx")



bsn<-function(x) if(nrow(subset(stns, STATION==x))>0) subset(stns, STATION==x)$BASIN else NA

lon<-function(x) if(nrow(subset(stns, STATION==x))>0) mean(subset(stns, STATION==x)$LONGITUDE) else NA

lat<-function(x) if(nrow(subset(stns, STATION==x))>0) mean(subset(stns, STATION==x)$LATITUDE) else NA



a$Basin=unlist(mapply(bsn, a$Stn), use.names=F)

a$Lat=unlist(mapply(lat, a$Stn), use.names=F)

a$Lon=unlist(mapply(lon, a$Stn), use.names=F)
```

Additionally here is a screenshot of the file that i would like r to act on
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O55qJ.png)

I will be back around to anwser any questions
Thank you for your time

Comment: The `setwd` function chages the R working directory. It's generally considered bad form to include that in a script since the path will be different on every computer. I'm  unclear on if you expect the path `C:/Users/JNunl/OneDrive/Desktop/RDATA/MichiganScriptR/LakeM/` to exist on your own computer or if that was the path in the script you downloaded. You'll want to change that path to point to where ever you downloaded the data. You can try removing the `setwd()` from you code and choosing `Session..Set Working Directory` from the RStudio menu to point to the file where the data is located.

Comment: C:/Users/JNunl/OneDrive/Desktop/RDATA/MichiganScriptR/LakeM/  is the folder that is on my pc where the data is. I think this may have fixed it but R returns an error. I believe it is attempting to evaluate variables that aren't defined. That may be a problem with the spreadsheet, maybe?

Comment: Your script does seem to have a random line with just `gb` on it. It's not clear why that's there. It just looks like a mistake. If the "cannot change working directory" error is no longer relevant, remove it from your question.

Comment: In R enter `choose.dir()` and then use the menus to navigate to the appropriate folder.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I recieved a copy pasted code from my script i am attempting to make edits to it so the script will run properly on my pc. Seems like the largest issue is renaming things so R studio knows what files to run and act on